# How to find the great parent by tag name onclick the nested child node in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My code is

```
<li>
    <a onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>
        <div className="gui-icon icon1">
            <i className="fa fa-image" ></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

And my onClick function is

```
handle(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
}
```

Upon onClick sometimes the console will give `<a>` tag, and when my click in on the `div` console gives `<div>` and when the click is on `i` the console gives `<i>`. 
My requirement is to add a class on `<i>` tag when I click. So I'm thinking to find the parent `<li>` and then update the class of its child node `<i>`.
How can I find the `<li>` as parent sometimes or great parent sometimes based on the click hits on `<a>` or `<div>` or `<i>`? Or any other solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to get to the outer `<li>`, if you only need to change the class of the innermost `<i>`?

Comment: Because my target is not always same when I console. It may be `a` or `div` or `i`

Comment: So? From any of them, you can find the inner `i` easily without having to go back up to the `<li>` first? Is there really something you want to do with the `li`?

Comment: Nothing to do with `li`. Just to find its child node `i` and update.

Comment: why cant you directly bind click event to li element ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a reference to the `li` - you just need a reference to the *innermost descendant* `<i>`, which can be done with `querySelector`:

```
handle(e) {
  const iTag = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('i');
  // do stuff with iTag
}
```

The `parentElement` is there so that the `querySelector` works even if the clicked element is the `i` tag itself. Alternatively, you could do:

```
handle(e) {
  const iTag = e.target.tagName === 'I'
    ? e.target
    : e.target.querySelector('i');
  // do stuff with iTag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tagName` property to make sure that you're on the right element. You could do something like this:

```
// Get a handle on the outer li tag
let currentNode = e.target
while (currentNode.tagName !== 'LI') {
  currentNode = currentNode.parentNode
}
// Do stuff with i tag
```

From there, if what you clicked on has a `li` parent element, you can use `currentNode` to do stuff with `i`.

Comment: Parent node may not be `<li>` always. I have mentioned it in the question

Comment: If it's not always an `<li>` you could either replace the tagname for those instances or use a consistent identifier like a class. If using a class instead of the `tagName` property, you could use `hasClass('NAME_OF_CLASS')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this JS code and on click event it will give you parent always

```
document.getElementById('li').onclick = function(event) {
   alert(this.tagName);
};
```

give li an id of 'li' or something else

Answer (score 0):

Just check the element tag name - if it is an `i`, update it, otherwise use `querySelector`:

```
handle(e) {
    if (e.target.tagname == "i") {
        //Update event.target
    } else {
        let elem = event.target.querySelector("i");
        //Update elem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with *this* object.

**Demo:**

```js
function handle(e, el) {
  el.children[0].children[0].classList.add('icon-color');
}
```

```css
.icon-color{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a onclick="handle(event, this)">a
    <div class="gui-icon icon1">div
      <i class="fa fa-image" >icon</i>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `pointer-events` of `div` to `none` using CSS so the `event.target` will always be the `a` tag

```html
<li>
    <a onClick={this.handle.bind(this)}>
        <div className="gui-icon icon1" style="pointer-events: none">
            <i className="fa fa-image" ></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

so in your javascript, this is how you navigate other elements

```
let liElement = event.target.parentElement
let divElement = event.target.firstElementChild
let iElement = event.target.firstElementChild.firstElementChild
```